# SilverStripe 3.1 Registry module

Tags: module, silverstripe

Anyone using the Registry module and have it rendering a custom template?
I'm following along with the example in the doco which says the following:

> As a further layer of customisation, you can create templates that
>   will be only used when viewing specific registries. So if you wanted
>   to create a template that would only be used to view the StaffMember
>   registry, you would create RegistryPage_StaffMember.ss and
>   RegistryPage_StaffMember_show.ss

My class is called `StaffMember`, I have the template in Layouts, it always falls back to `Page.ss` - however the `RegistryPage_StaffMember_show.ss` template does render for a specific item when clicking through.

[Registry Doco](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-registry/blob/master/docs/en/index.md)

Thx
Dave

Answer (score 0):

For now I added an index action to the modules controller which seems to work.

```
public function index()
    {
        return $this->renderWith($this->getTemplateList('index'));
    }
```